# comparing System::String^ to std::string

Tags: string, c++-cli, string-comparison, stdstring

I have a `Generic::List(String^)^ myList` and some `std::string & myValue` values, and I need to check that the values are all contained in the list.  (I don't want to add values to the list).

What do I do in place of `myList->Contains(myValue)` to be sure I'm comparing the contents of the strings?

I know I can use InteropServices to marshal each element of the list.

I could convert the Generic::List to a cli::array if that would help!

Thanks
Melanie

Comment: Comparing strings with different encodings is funny business.  Sometimes different characters are supposed to compare equal.  Do you know whether your list will ever include non-ASCII characters?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the `List<T>::Contains(T)` documentation (C# documentation, but that doesn't affect anything):

*This method determines equality by using the default equality comparer, as defined by the object's implementation of the IEquatable.Equals method for T (the type of values in the list).*

Because `String::Equals(String^)` compares the contents of the strings, all that is necessary is converting the `std::string` to a `System::String^`. You can do that with a `marshal_as` and you should be good.